# LINQ orderby int array index value

Tags: arrays, linq, sql-order-by, int

Using LINQ I would like to sort by the passed in int arrays index.

So in the code below attribueIds is my int array. I'm using the integers in that array for the where clause but I would like the results in the order that they were in while in the array.

```
public List BuildTable(int[] attributeIds)
{
    using (var dc = new MyDC())
    {
        var ordering = attributeIds.ToList();

        var query = from att in dc.DC.Ecs_TblAttributes
                    where attributeIds.Contains(att.ID)
                    orderby(ordering.IndexOf(att.ID))
                    select new Common.Models.Attribute
                    {
                        AttributeId = att.ID,
                        DisplayName = att.DisplayName,
                        AttributeName = att.Name
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't not setting an order keep the original order?

Comment: You want the result to be ordered in the way numbers appear in incoming array, right? And your method does not do that?

Comment: I think you may need to be a bit clearer about exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to sort by multiple columns? For example, if you pass in the values '2' and '3' do you want to generate a query with `orderby <column 2>, <column 3>`?

Comment: var attributeIds = [26, 40, 41, 21, 71, 39]; I want the results returned in the order that they are in the array, so 26,40,41,21 ect. not 21,26,39,40,41 ect. Which is what is happening by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend selecting from the attributeIDs array instead. This will ensure that your items will be correctly ordered without requiring a sort.

The code should go something like this:

```
var query = 
from id in attributeIds
let att = dc.DC.Ecs_TblAttributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id)
where att != null
select new Common.Models.Attribute
{
    AttributeId = att.ID,
    DisplayName = att.DisplayName,
    AttributeName = att.Name
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you join:

```
public List BuildTable(int[] attributeIds)
{
    using (var dc = new MyDC())
    {
        var query = from attID in attributeIds
                    join att in dc.DC.Ecs_TblAttributes
                    on attID equals att.ID
                    select new Common.Models.Attribute
                           {
                               AttributeId = attID,
                               DisplayName = att.DisplayName,
                               AttributeName = att.Name
                           };
         return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this one as it works with LINQToSQL and executing on the DB